# Same Column check in SQL Server insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table `dom` with these two columns (`FLAT_AMOUNT`, `FLAT_PERCENTAGE`).

I am going to insert data into the table `dom`:

```
INSERT INTO Dom(FLAT_AMOUNT, FLAT_PERCENTAGE)
    SELECT 
        CASE
           WHEN FLAT_PERCENTAGE = 0 THEN 0
        END AS FLAT_AMOUNT,
        CASE
           WHEN PN_TYPE = 'AD' THEN 0
           WHEN PN_TYPE = 'OD' THEN 1
           WHEN PN_TYPE IN('SB', 'FP', 'AM', 'G') THEN 2
           ELSE 0
        END AS FLAT_PERCENTAGE
    FROM
        PENNUM
```

I hope you got my point. Is there a possible way to check same column values in the table to make insert for other column?

Comment: Domnic your select statement is missing the FROM clause, It was also missing the the comma after the first case statement (I insert it there for you). Could you show your query and I might be able to help you.

Comment: I have edited the scripts pls chk

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly this is what you want done:

```
INSERT INTO    Dom(FLAT_AMOUNT
              , FLAT_PERCENTAGE)
      SELECT CASE
               WHEN FLAT_PERCENTAGE = 0 THEN 0
            END AS FLAT_AMOUNT
          , CASE
               WHEN PN_TYPE = 'AD' THEN 0
               WHEN PN_TYPE = 'OD' THEN 1
               WHEN PN_TYPE IN('SB', 'FP', 'AM', 'G') THEN 2
               ELSE 0
            END AS FLAT_PERCENTAGE
      FROM   PENNUM AS A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Dom AS B ON CASE
                                     WHEN A.PN_TYPE = 'AD' THEN 0
                                     WHEN A.PN_TYPE = 'OD' THEN 1
                                     WHEN A.PN_TYPE IN('SB', 'FP', 'AM', 'G') THEN 2
                                     ELSE 0
                                  END = B.FLAT_PERCENTAGE
                                  AND CASE
                                        WHEN A.FLAT_PERCENTAGE = 0 THEN 0
                                     END = B.FLAT_PERCENTAGE
      WHERE  B.FLAT_AMOUNT IS NULL
            AND B.FLAT_PERCENTAGE IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can repeat the logic:

```
INSERT INTO Dom(FLAT_AMOUNT,FLAT_PERCENTAGE)
  SELECT (CASE WHEN PN_TYPE NOT IN ('OD', 'SB', 'FP', 'AM', 'G') THEN 0
          END) AS FLAT_AMOUNT,
         (CASE WHEN PN_TYPE = 'AD' THEN 0
               WHEN PN_TYPE = 'OD' THEN 1
               WHEN PN_TYPE IN('SB', 'FP', 'AM', 'G') THEN 2
               ELSE 0
          END) AS FLAT_PERCENTAGE
    FROM PENNUM ;
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery, CTE, or even `outer apply` so your query doesn't have to repeat logic:

```
INSERT INTO Dom(FLAT_AMOUNT,FLAT_PERCENTAGE)
  SELECT (CASE WHEN x.FLAT_PERCENTAGE = 0 THEN 0
          END) AS FLAT_AMOUNT,
         x.FLAT_PERCENTAGE
    FROM PENNUM p OUTER APPLY
         (SELECT (CASE WHEN p.PN_TYPE = 'AD' THEN 0
                       WHEN p.PN_TYPE = 'OD' THEN 1
                       WHEN p.PN_TYPE IN ('SB', 'FP', 'AM', 'G') THEN 2
                       ELSE 0
                  END) as FLAT_PERCENTAGE
         ) x;
```